# Resizeable iframes wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, iframe, plugins, resize, drag

I want 2 iframes side by side in same window so that if drag and resize the left iframe the size of right iframe must change according to left same window like below 
There are 3 frames html,css,js .. codepen.io website code editor window..just need the plugin for such multiple resizeable iframes

Comment: 1. Show your code. 2. Show what you have tried so far. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have used plugin advanced iframe pro ..in wordpress